# set object expiry date for amazon s3 object using java sdk

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload a file in amazon S3 storage using java sdk, enabling a explicit expiration date for the object using objectMetadata. when I run the program it uploads to S3 and sets the expiration date to object metadata as expected but eventually it doesn't seem to be deleted after the expiration date. I am not sure where i am doing wrong. Below is the code snippet i used to set the object metadata.

```
PutObjectRequest putObjectRequest = new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, key, file);
ObjectMetadata objectMetadata = new ObjectMetadata();
objectMetadata.setHttpExpiresDate(new DateTime().plusDays(1).toDate());
putObjectRequest.setMetadata(objectMetadata);
return s3.putObject(putObjectRequest);
```

I have been going through some of the Amazon documentation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/manage-lifecycle-using-java.html which says to set the BucketLifeCycle Configuration rule. I am not sure whether if i apply this rule will it be applied to all folders and objects under this bucket or only the objects i upload using this rule through my java program?

Please suggest, Thanks in advance !

Comment: `setHttpExpiresDate()` sets the `Expires` HTTP header, to tell browsers when to consider the object stale.  It does not set a lifecycle expiration for the object.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot, is there a way to set object expiration date with out setting rule for whole bucket life cycle?

Comment: You can set a lifecycle rule for the whole bucket that only deletes objects having a specific tag after a certain number of days, or you can create a lifecycle rule to match only objects matching specific name criteria.  You can't directly set expiration for individual objects.

Answer (score 1):

Following the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/ObjectMetadata.html#setExpirationTime-java.util.Date-) you can’t directly set expiration date for particular object.

To solve this problem you can:

1. Define lifecycle rule for a bucket(remove bucket with objects after number of days)
2. Define lifecycle rule for bucket to remove objects with specific tag or prefix after numbers of days

To creating a rules use documentation:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/how-to-set-lifecycle-configuration-intro.html